# PHP Solr Xpath Error: no elements found

Tags: php, xpath, solr

https://github.com/php/pecl-search_engine-solr/blob/master/solr_functions_client.c#L564

**PECL Info**

```
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
solr 2.0.0 stable
```

**PHP Version** 5.3.6

**Solr Version** 4.9.0

I'm using a fresh installation of this program, using the /example/start.jar package with no configurations altered. The admin panel come up perfectly fine. However, the application built around this tech is returning the following error when trying to do a Lucene-based query:

```
PHP Warning:  SolrClient::query(): Xpath Error: no elements found
```

Solr worked on my local environment with the difference being PHP's version, set to 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3. Could this have been a factor?

Comment: What does the Solr server log say when you're querying it? I'm guessing you're getting an exception or the core isn't being loaded at all, so the app container is just returning an error message instead of XML content.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, on me it was the following:
The problem is it don't find the corresponding solr core / collection.
The php solr implementation (seams to) use by default the core named "collection1" if this one does not exist the error "Xpath Error: no elements found" will occure.

To fix the problem, you can **set the PATH to the collection/core** name you have used.
You have to set the path to the URL part after http:// host:port as you can see in Solr Admin if you execute a query.
Example:
you core is named "recipes",
the query url would be: http://localhost:8983/solr/recipes/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true
so you need the path "/solr/recipes"

For setting path you can do: (based on http://php.net/manual/en/solr.examples.php)

```
define('SOLR_PATH', '/solr/recipes');

$options = array
(
    'hostname' => SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME,
    'login'    => SOLR_SERVER_USERNAME,
    'password' => SOLR_SERVER_PASSWORD,
    'port'     => SOLR_SERVER_PORT,
    'path'     => SOLR_PATH,
);

$client = new SolrClient($options);

$doc = new SolrInputDocument();

$doc->addField('id', 334455);
$doc->addField('cat', 'Software');
$doc->addField('cat', 'Lucene');

$updateResponse = $client->addDocument($doc);

print_r($updateResponse->getResponse());
```